# How to use the same DragonBones Armature several times

Tags: air, starling-framework

I have Adobe AIR application written with [Starling framework](http://gamua.com/starling/) and [DragonBones library](http://dragonbones.github.io).
I'm loading an armature of teleport that I show when a character is enter into the screen.
In the game there can be a situation in which 4 characters enter at the same time.

Is there a way to load the teleport armature once and clone it to be able to show it 4 times on screen?

Comment: p.s. Can someone with 1500 points please add dragonbones tag to SO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I had to do it simply call factory.build several times.